# my first programing language ANTLR package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist

Tags: intellij-idea, antlr

[image]

I try to create my first Programming Language Using ANTLR4 using IntelliJ IDEA.
Everything is ok until I changed the output directory where all output is generated to catalog src from gen. I got an error:

Error:(3, 28) java: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist

```
C:\Users\PanKomputer>echo %CLASSPATH%
.;‪E:\Pobrane\antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar
```

Comment: IntelliJ apparently isn't looking at your `%CLASSPATH%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`E:\Pobrane\antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar` needs to be configured as a library and [added to the module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).